# Why does saving strings into this a *char array from STDIN only save the last line in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, getline

I am reading in from a file using STDIN using getline and saving each line onto a *char array.
Here is a sample input file:

```
T4
T2
T1
T1
S9
T5
S1
T1
T1
T1
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
 char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t lineSize = 0;
    char* transactions[250];

    int i = 0;
    while((lineSize = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
        printf("You entered %s, which has %zu chars.\n", line, lineSize - 1);
        transactions[i] = line;
        printf("Added in %s\n", transactions[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("transaction[%d] = %s\n", j, transactions[j]);
    }
    
    
    free(line);
```

This is my output:

```
my_shell>./prod 12 2 < inputexample.txt
nthreads: 12
id: 2
You entered T4
, which has 3 chars.
Added in T4

You entered T2
, which has 3 chars.
Added in T2

You entered T1
, which has 3 chars.
Added in T1

You entered T1
, which has 3 chars.
Added in T1

You entered S9
, which has 3 chars.
Added in S9

You entered T5
, which has 3 chars.
Added in T5

You entered S1
, which has 3 chars.
Added in S1

You entered T1
, which has 3 chars.
Added in T1

You entered T1
, which has 3 chars.
Added in T1

You entered T1, which has 1 chars.
Added in T1


transaction[0] = T1
transaction[1] = T1
transaction[2] = T1
transaction[3] = T1
transaction[4] = T1
transaction[5] = T1
transaction[6] = T1
transaction[7] = T1
transaction[8] = T1
transaction[9] = T1
```

As you can see, the while loops successfully writes AND reads the proper element from the *transactions array. However, when I check it again in the for loop, it returns consistently a singular element. What is going on here? I am printing from transactions[i] the same way from the while loop, just using a different iterator.

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different languages. Tag only the language your code is written in(related to).

Comment: `getline` only reallocates memory when necessary, so you store the same pointer over and over.

Comment: `transactions[i] = line;` you need to copy memory here

Comment: @Ôrel or reset `line = NULL` and `len = 0` before each call of `getline` so that a new buffer gets allocated.

Comment: Just a side note, but `free`ing just `line` is not correct; you need to free *all* lines stored in `transaction` – once you fixed the code.

Comment: @datenwolf Actually even suffices to reset `line` only; [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline): *'\*lineptr may be null, in which case \*n is ignored [...]'*

Comment: I personally would skip `line` *entirely* and pass `transactions + i` directly (`getline(tranactions + i, &len, stdin)`); though requires initialisation of the array then: `char* transactions[250] = { NULL };`